# Domain Driven Design - Implementation as a set of nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, nuget, domain-driven-design

I live and preach DDD, and almost every single project that I develop ends up on the form:

```
- Application Layer
- Business Layer 
- Domain Layer
- Data Layer
```

Each layer here is a set of executables or dll's that together form the application. Each of the dlls target net48, dotnetcore3.1 and netstandard2.1 for maximum reusability.

Recently, in a hobby project, I've had the reusability advantage in sharing components and definitions across a WPF app, a WebAPI and a set of Azure Functions. But now, my need expands to include a mobile (Xamarin) app, so I figured I'd move the domain layer into a nuget package, and then pull in different implementations into the different applications. This makes it easy to redo things like authentication, logging etc implemented specifically for the new Mobile app, since the definitions of the domain are in a nuget package.

I'm wondering wether my approach is sound. The benefits of having the nuget packages are good to an extent, but at the same time, fixing small things, or adding a property to an Entity requires me to republish and update versions. Unit-Tests take care of the logic, but I still miss the ability to do a good old-fashioned debug.

What are your thoughts and experiences with this approach?

Comment: Hey. Interesting would be good a bit more info on what the different layers represent, particularly around what's in the Application and Business Layers? Do you consider Applications to be WebAPI, WPF etc?  Personally, I think of the Application layer as the Services / Gateway to the application (inc. coordination), with the Domain side being the models and factories, that define the particular domain actors (aggregates +). NB. There are various ways to solve this, but I'd like to know a little more first.

Comment: I typically keep all orchestration classes in the business layer (to stay SOLID). That is how I see service classes, as orchestrators that combine validators and repositories. 

Application layer to me is the layer where the actual executable is, an ASP.NET project, UWP Project, Xamarin etc. 

The domain layer contains only declarations, entities, value types and all of the interfaces that are implemented elsewhere.

Comment: I ask because I would consider the Application to be a combination of the Service and the Domain models.  Then the API, WPF App etc, to be "interfaces" (plugins) to your actual application.  Therefore you actual want to package up the application itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing the Domain layer as NuGet packages (in DDD) is exactly what we are currently busy with. I'm talking about a large business solution that has some "Shared" Domain and followed by region-specific implementations.

Sharing a common domain can be hard work and I would suggest only going for this approach if it strategically lines up with your business needs.

From my experience here's what I would suggest:

- Avoid a big-bang approach. Do not start with shared Domain on Day 1. You can start with implementing the entire Domain for one region/ application.
- Keep in mind that 90% of identical Business Domain is not the same as a completely identical business Domain. Be prepared to spend considerable time in designing that 10% different domain for your applications :)
- Identify common components. Move them into a separate project within the same solution for a start. Common components could include, common Business Logic, infrastructure layer, etc. I would suggest doing this in conjunction with your Business team.
- The "common" business layer could just be a set of abstract classes of Aggregates, Entities, ValueObjects, etc.
- Ensure that you have appropriate test coverage for your "common" code.
- Avoid `enums`. Use [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types). Unlike `enum`, `Enumeration` class can be inherited. This can be useful when you need to extend your `Enumeration` in a specific implementation.
- The methods/behaviors in a Domain model other than `Aggregate` are usually `internal`.You need to be careful while moving your methods/behavior to the common NuGet packages. Making them `public` would mean that the Domain models could be modified from outside. You may have need to make them `protected` and then let the derived class in the application inherit the Domain object.
- Once, you are happy with the set up move the common Domain project into a separate solution as a Nuget package.

Comment: My apps typically have repositories, declared in interfaces, and implemented in their own dlls, i.e. "IProductRepository" and "IAddressRepository" are both declared in the domain, but implemented in <projectname>.data.sqlserver, so in the case of me ever wanting to move the implementation of IAddressRepository to Azure Storage, I'd simply implement it in <projectname>.data.azurestorage. In todays solutions, this can mean quite a handful of dlls - authentication, email transmission, messagebrokering, even file IO. My biggest concern about this approach is the debugging - how do you approach it?

Comment: I think your question is more around debugging a nuget package. You could use SourceLink or you could also try Nuget extension such as NugetReferenceSwitcher https://github.com/RicoSuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher. See my post of Nuget Standard and Defaults, you may find it useful. https://ankitvijay.net/2020/03/29/nuget-packages-our-standards-and-defaults/

Comment: Oh that was PRECICELY what I needed, Ankit! Thank you EVER so much!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-)